# WordPress display gallery of images with different height

Tags: html, wordpress, zurb-foundation, gallery, custom-post-type

I need to display images into landing page built on WordPress. Images should be displayed like this:

https://i.ibb.co/vk8MqkK/sample.png

What is the best way to display this layout on WordPress without any plugins?

I wanted to present each image as Custom Post Tyle and use WP_Query to dynamically load them into my landing page. But in HTML each image has different classes to create such layout - Image 2 and Image 3 are wrapped in `<div class="grid-y">`

**HTML (+Foundation XY-grid classes)**

```
<div class="grid-container full">
  <div class="grid-x">

    <!-- Image 1 -->
    <div class="cell large-6">
      <img src="img/product-0.jpg" class="width-100 height-100" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="cell large-6" >
      <div class="grid-y">

        <!-- Image 2 -->
        <div class="cell large-6">
          <img src="img/product-31.jpg" class="width-100 height-50" alt="">
        </div>

        <!-- Image 3 -->
        <div class="cell large-6">
          <img src="img/product-31.jpg" class="width-100 height-50" alt="">
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing any markup, you can try something like this: https://codepen.io/paka/pen/LeBbOW
Display the cells in grid-x box as inline-block but not those inside the grid-y block, so they are aranged one under the other.
With this css you get your layout: *I added some heights and widths and colors to substituate your images*

```
`.grid-x{
  position: relative ;
  height: 100px ;
  width: 205px ;
  padding: 0px ;
}

.grid-y > .cell:first-of-type{
  background: blue ;
}

.grid-y > .cell{
  background: red ;
}

.grid-x > .cell:first-of-type{
  height: 100px ;
  width: 100px ;

  background: #00ff00 ;
}

.grid-y {
  margin: 0px ;
  padding: 0px ;
}
.grid-y > .cell{
  padding: 0px ;
  margin: 0px ;
  height: 50px ;
  width: 100px ;
}

.grid-x > .cell{
  display: inline-block ;
}`
```